# cakePHP associated data not retrieved

Tags: cakephp, model, has-many-through

This problem's been bashing my brains for days. When i perform a find('all') on my Department model, no associated data is fetched. Here's my Department model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Department extends AppModel {

public $displayField = 'name';
//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

public $belongsTo = array( ///check
    'District' => array(
        'className' => 'District',
        'foreignKey' => 'district_id'
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'department_id' ///check
    ),
    'Request'=>array(
        'className' => 'Request',
        'foreignKey' => 'department_id',
    ),
    'DepartmentPosition'=>array(
        'className'=>'DepartmentPosition',
        'foreignKey'=>'department_id',
        'dependent'=>true
    ),
);
```

}

When I do find('all'), it returns all fields from every department in the database, but no associated data at all. in the departments controller:

```
$departments = $this->Department->find('all');
$this->set(compact('departments'));
```

It feels like i have a problem in the model because I'm having no issues with any of the other models and returning associated data, including one's related to Department. For instance, I can find all of the Departments related to a District.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post all parameters of find().

Comment: yes, there are none at this point. i'm just doing find('all') at this point, and then in the view doing debug($departments). Thanks @Danial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect model file naming is the most common cause of your model file not being read and cake using an AppModel instance for the table. So check your model's file name. Ensure it's `Department.php`. In your controller do `debug(get_class($this->Department));` its should return "Department" and not "AppModel".

Assuming your model file is loaded properly and you still have problem most likely cause is model's `$recursive` property is set to -1, perhaps in AppModel.

Answer (score 0):

You should use following :

```
$this->Department->recursive = 1;
$departments = $this->Department->find('all');
$this->set(compact('departments'));
```

Comment: As i said in the question, it's not an issue of controller code. I'm getting NO related data back, regardless of what i type in the controller.